# Use sp_executesql to run xp_cmdshell with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Trying to run xp_cmdshell with sp_executesql without success, database is SQL Server 2008R2

Here is the SQL

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''BCP "SELECT data FROM TableA WHERE id = @id" queryout C:\Temp\test.dat -T -N'''
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@id numeric(19, 0)', @id = 1234
```

The error is

```
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@id".
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Did you forgot to declare @id?  DECLARE @id numeric(19, 0);

Comment: @MihaiHantea I did that in the parameter list of the sp_executesql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the @id variable reference in your @sql string being in an escaped-sub-string (i.e. the BCP string being executed by xp_cmdshell). So you *could* just escape out of that sub-string.

```
DECLARE @id NUMERIC(19, 0)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @id = 1234
SET @SQL = N'DECLARE @BCP NVARCHAR(4000); 
SET @BCP = ''BCP "SELECT data FROM TableA WHERE id = ''
           + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @id) + N''" queryout C:\Temp\test.dat -T -N'';
PRINT @BCP
EXEC xp_cmdshell @BCP;
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@id NUMERIC(19, 0)', @id = 1234
```

But that is still more effort than is needed here. Just concatenate the @id value into the string and then use EXEC(). There is no need to use sp_executesql as you don't need the performance benefit of caching the query plan.

```
DECLARE @id NUMERIC(19, 0)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @id = 1234
SET @SQL = N'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''BCP "SELECT data FROM TableA WHERE id = '  
           + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @id) + N'" queryout C:\Temp\test.dat -T -N'''

PRINT @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is a workaround I can do, but thats not my question about. My question was about why it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @user1589188: it's not a work-around; it's a cleaner solution to what you are trying to accomplish. However, I did update my answer to reflect that specific question. I can update again to show an example of it.

Comment: Yes thanks for the edit. To phase my question again "How do you use sp_executesql to run xp_cmdshell with a variable inside". Not possible is an acceptable answer if thats the limitation of sp_executesql.

Comment: @user1589188: I have updated my answer to include an example doing what you originally set out to do. I tested it and it does work. If this is good for you, please don't forget to mark as the accepted answer. Thanks :).

Comment: Thanks so much! Love it how you can get around the syntax limitation and create a workable solution. Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the variable @id doesn't exist in the scope of the procedure xp_cmdshell.
In other words, @id is not being replaced with the actual value in the string `SELECT data FROM TableA WHERE id = @id`. Better replace the variable called @id and then execute your query.

```
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'@id',@id);
```

Your code updated:

```
DECLARE @id NUMERIC(19, 0)
SET @id = 3087

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''BCP "SELECT data FROM TableA WHERE id = @id" queryout "C:\Temp\test.dat" -T -N '''
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'@id',@id);
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Ah yes, a string replace does the trick here. But it defeats the purpose to have parameter list (e.g. multiple parameter you will need to have multiple REPLACE) and that is not a parameter list anymore. Although clever, I think srutzky's answer is closer to the nature of the question.