# Declare dynamic table which will use later in sql server procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on sql stored procedure and I got some issue description given below:

**Working Process**

Declare a table name `@summaryTable`

`DECLARE @summaryTable table (
id int identity(1,1),
)`

Then make a query and then insert data into table `@summaryTable`, code given below:

`set @query = "Select * from Foo"
insert into @summaryTable exec(@query)`

**Problem**

When I print table name such as `print @summaryTable`, simply it give me the
 error that

```
`Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure summaryReportExport, Line 71
Must declare the scalar variable "@summaryTable".`
```

Actually I need to use above table-name while creating *.csv* file such as

```
Declare @resultSet nvarchar(max)
set @resultSet = "Select foo from '+@summaryTable"
Declare @sql varchar(8000) set @sql = 'xp_cmdshell  '
Declare @fileName varchar(8000) set @fileName = 'c:/test.csv'
set @sql = @sql +   '''' + ' bcp "' + @resultSet+'"'  +' queryout '+ @fileName  +' -T -c -t,' + '''' ;
print @sql
EXEC    (@sql)
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary tables come in different flavours including, amongst others, local temporary tables (starting with `#`), global temporary tables (starting with `##`), persistent temporary tables (prefixed by TempDB..), and table variables.(starting with (`@`)

if we declare with `@tableName` then it works as a variable it should be the part of query.Table variables are used within the scope of the routine or batch within which they are defined

```
   DECLARE @summaryTable table (
    id int identity(1,1),
    )
```

if you declare `#tableName` it's mean local table only you can use it for this session.With Local temporary table (names that begin with `#`), what goes on under the hood is surprisingly similar to table variables. As with Table Variables, Local Temporary tables are private to the process that created it. They cannot therefore be used in views and you cannot associate triggers with them

```
  CREATE TABLE #summaryTable  (
        id int identity(1,1),
        )
```

if you declare `##tableName` it's mean global table any one can use for this session.Like Local temporary tables, Global temporary tables (they begin with `##`) are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends: However, because global tables aren’t private to the process that created it, they must persist thereafter until the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the table at the time when the creating session ended has finished executing and the locks are dropped. Anyone who has access to TempDB at the time these Global Temporary tables exist can directly query, modify or drop these temporary objects.

You can associate rules, defaults, and indexes with temporary tables, but you cannot create views on temporary tables or associate triggers with them. You can use a user-defined datatype when creating a temporary table only if the datatype exists in TempDB

```
  CREATE TABLE ##summaryTable  (
        id int identity(1,1),
        )
```

this [Reference](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/) more help you

Comment: I appreciate your help ! thanks . Next , when I use `#` with table as you mention above then it give me error that `The name "#temp" is not permitted in this context`. Can you please elaborate one thing for me that is there any possibility that I could use ( or print it) table variable (or table name whatever you name it)  at the end of the procedure?

Comment: @Zeb see this example `create proc test
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'declare @temp table 
(val int)

insert into @temp values (1),(2),(3)
select * from @temp'
exec (@sql)` and test `exec test` i hope this will give you right direction. we should just make sure our table variable should be in scope thats it

Comment: yes it's working fine , but I need the name of table so that I can use it for other purpose , as you declare `@temp` table in above example. I want the name of table so that I can create `.csv` file by putting table name into it.

Comment: @Zeb do one thing use `##tblName` OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777561/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `CREATE TABLE #TableName (id int identity(1,1))` this will create a temp table. And then add `DROP TABLE #TableName` to the end of you script.

But iam not sure what it is you want with this? You are trying to read a file into somthing ?

For more information on Temp Tables, read: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/ and http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables .